# mutiple subqueries error.please let me know how can i solve this

Tags: hive

trying to run below code in hue editor but failing for mutiple subqueris.please let me know how to solve this.

```
SELECT a.app,a.app_content,a.app_provider,b.app,b.date_hr,b.transdate from
(SELECT * FROM table1)a
left join
(select * from table2
        WHERE date_hr=(select max(date_hr )from table2

         and transdate=(select max(transdate) from table2)b
on a.app=b.app;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
SELECT a.app,a.app_content,a.app_provider,b.app,b.date_hr,b.transdate
from table1 a
left join (select app,max(date_hr) date_hr,max(transdate) transdate from table2 group by app) b
    on a.app=b.app;
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.max(date_hr) column is not there in table2 and i have to filter the data in table2 based on max(date_hr) and max(transdate).can i use hive variable to assign max values and use them in the script.Please help me on this

Comment: Try executing the above statement and see if its giving expected results.